# What was the significance of the ending in Kaafiron Ki Namaaz?

Tags: analysis, ending, kaafiron-ki-namaaz

In [Kaafiron Ki Namaaz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3095248/), they raised so many controversial topics like homosexuality, anti-Gandhism, rape, Kashmir issue, media faking, religion, Ayodhya dispute, etc. just by a conversation between a court martialed army officer, a writer, a wannabe singer cum tea stall guy (Junaid) and a mute spectator (cameraman).

But in the end in a drunken state, Junaid (singer) kills Army man and writer and even got killed by cameraman in self defense. But what does it imply to the story? What significance does this event serve to the story?

Comment: Downvoters are welcome to leave comments :\

Comment: @iandotkelly: They _should_ but it is not _must_.

Answer (score -1):

I have never reviewed a movie before. I am not a critic or an avid movie reviewer.

But I am going to answer this question because I felt the writer of the movie was trying to convey a message.

The movie was not about Kashmir or the situation in Kashmir. It was about inner conflict. Most opinions were canned, for example soldier's views on Gandhi and Independence. Many views were carefully drafted, for example the writer telling soldier that he is just a mere puppet (aren't we all mere puppets, because many people believe the media, pamphlets, news, books etc. All you have to do is justify what you write, it doesn't has to be right).

In my opinion, you could relate this whole movie to a number of different setups, but it does fit into the current political scenario from a far left liberal view.

I am not going to comment on Junaid, Soldier or Writer. But I think the cameraman is us, the viewers. We are watching almost every thing, but we do nothing. And we try to tell ourselves "Maine kuch nahi kia", & we run away, putting our heads in the sand like ostriches.

It was not a great movie, the hype was too much.

Comment: But I was seeking for the significance of ending for the film